# How to overcome the developer console error while saving the edited record?

Tags: developer-console

I am using the salesforce from the last 3 months, as I am new to salesforce I stuck with the Developer console error.

In Developer console, while I am saving the edited file or creating a new file, showing the following error.

> Failed to create createContainerMember for
>   containerId=1dc28000000MhWTAA0: This container member belongs to a
>   container that currently has an unfinished save request with
>   deploymentId=1dr28000001LPuc. You may not modify any members in this
>   container until it completes.: Metadata Container ID

Without the developer console, it is a bit late for me to do the apex classes or triggers. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please create a new workspace from the Developer Console

Go to Developer Console -> Work Space -> New Workspace
Create a new workspace

2. Save classes/triggers

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000204953&language=en_US